# AWS Fargate Prices Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have set up a Task Definition with CPU maximum allocation of 1024 units and 2048 MiB of memory with Fargate being the launch type. When I looked at the costs it was way more expensive than I thought ($ 1.00 per day or $ 0.06 per hour [us-east-1]). What I did was to reduce to 256 units and I am waiting to see if the costs goes down. But How does the Task maximum allocation work? Is the task definition maximum allocation responsible for Fargate provisioning a more powerfull server with a higher cost even if I dont use 100%?

The apps in containers running 24/7 are NestJS application + apache (do not ask why) + redis and I can see that it has low CPU usage but the price is too high for me. Is the fargate the wrong choice for this? Should I go for EC2 instances with ECS?

Comment: Yes. You pay for provisioned CPU and RAM. It does not matter your application does not use 100% of these.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know that.

Answer (score 5):

When you run a task, Fargate provisions a container with the resources you have requested. It's not a question of "use *up to* this maximum CPU and memory," but rather "use *this much* CPU and memory." You'll pay for that much CPU and memory for as long as it runs, as per the [AWS Fargate pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/). At the current costs, the CPU and memory you listed (1024 CPU units, 2048MiB), the cost would come to $0.04937/hour, or $1.18488/day, or $35.55/month.

Whether Fargate is the right or wrong choice is subjective. It depends what you're optimizing for. If you just want to hand off a container and allow AWS to manage everything about how it runs, it's hard to beat ECS Fargate. OTOH, if you are optimizing for lowest cost, on-demand Fargate is probably not the best choice. You could use Fargate Spot ($10.66/month) if you can tolerate [the constraints of spot](https://www.scalefactory.com/blog/2020/07/27/the-trouble-with-fargate-spot/). Alternatively, you could use an EC2 instance (t3.small @ $14.98/month), but then you'll be responsible for managing everything.

You didn't mention how you're running Redis which will factor in here as well. If you're running Redis on Elasticache, you'll incur that cost as well, but you won't have to manage anything. If you end up using an EC2 instance, you could run Redis on the same instance, saving latency and expense, with the trade off that you'll have to install/operate Redis yourself.

Ultimately, you're making tradeoffs between time saved and money spent on managed services.